# Nunit framework - Order the testcases using Category

Tags: nunit

Need to run atleast 5 test cases in order.
Could u please let me know, how to run only those test case first in testsuite.

Comment: What are you using to run them? The NUnit GUI, nunit-console.exe, the VS plugin, ... what?

Comment: We are using VS plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Your tests should be able to run independently without relying on other tests for setup.

However, since NUnit runs tests alphabetically you can give them a prefix to order them such as:

```
Test01_ThisTestShouldRunFirst()
Test02_RunSecond()
```

Alternatively you could use tags to run your tests in sets:

```
[Category=("FirstTest")]
public void SomeTest()

[Category=("SecondTest")]
public void SomeOtherTest()
```

I'd like to stress that both of these are pretty dirty and your tests should be independent.